# Absolute Positioning is not working as I wanted to

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, positioning

The element I'm trying to position is still positioned inside of its parent even though I have positioned it absolute.

HTML

```
<div class="panel">
  '... other elements'
  <cuik-url-box
    (urlsEvent)="setUrls($event)"
    [hidden]="!state.urlToggle"
  ></cuik-url-box>
  <cuik-img-upload
    (files)="setTempImages($event)"
    [hidden]="!state.imgUploadToggle"
  ></cuik-img-upload>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.panel {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: theme.$secondary;
  border: 2px solid theme.$primary;
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: theme.$primary;
  font-family: theme.$Poppins;

  cuik-url-box,
  cuik-img-upload {
    position: absolute;

    &:is(cuik-url-box) {
      top: 50%;
      right: -50%;
      transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    }
    &:is(cuik-img-upload) {
      top: 50%;
      left: -50%;
      transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    }
  }
}
```

Heres The style of the ancestor

```
cuik-app-creator,
cuik-app-editor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba($color: theme.$secondary, $alpha: 0.05);
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CaSC.png)

Answer (score 1):

[An absolutely-positioned element is positioned **relative to its closest positioned ancestor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).  That is to say, to the nearest ancestor that has some non-`static` `position` styling being applied to it.  This is *only* the `<body />` element when there are *no* positioned ancestors.

For example, here is a case where the containing ancestors are *not* positioned, so the `absolute` element is relative to the viewport:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: black solid 2px;
}

.child-element {
  border: black dashed 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Parent Element<p>
  <div class="child-element">
    <p>Child Element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now look what happens if we add a `position: relative` to the parent element:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: black solid 2px;
  position: relative; /* In this example the parent is relatively-positioned */
}

.child-element {
  border: black dashed 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Parent Element<p>
  <div class="child-element">
    <p>Child Element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, in the first snippet the child is positioned relative to the viewport, where in the second it is positioned relative to the containing parent.

If you want your absolutely positioned element to be positioned relative to the viewport, you'll either need to remove positioning from all ancestors or you'll need to append it to the end of the `<body />` (or otherwise move it up in the hierarchy until it is not contained in a positioned element, but hiding it in an arbitrary location is probably going to lead to poor maintainability).